# error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load when lifting sails app using postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js, sails-postgresql

**So I get this 2 error:**

error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!

error: error: password authentication failed for user "root"

This is my connections.js file:

```js
module.exports.connections = {
PostgresqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    host: 'localhost',
    //user: 'Testeur1', // optional
    //password: 'eniso2020', // optional
    //database: 'PatientsDB' //optional
  }
  };
```

and this is the Patients.js file in the models folder:

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

  },
  connection:'PostgresqlServer'
};
```

Sails v 0.12.14

Any idea what can cause this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Uncomment this block of code `//user: 'Testeur1', // optional
    //password: 'eniso2020', // optional
    //database: 'PatientsDB' //optional` and ensure your db credentials are correct.

Comment: so when i do that I still get the first error and the second error just become: error: password authentication failed for user "Testeur1" .

Comment: and are you sure the user and password for the database are correct?

Comment: yeah I think so, here's a screen shot of postgres interface (https://ibb.co/dor7AH)

Comment: The owner and database look fine, sails is suggesting the issue is with your password.